# TextBox content doesn't bind to source WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am new to WPF and have come across a problem.
I have an MVVM WPF application and I want to implement filtering to my DataGrid. I have tried all possible solutions on the internet, but none of them work for me for some reason. I have created a TextBox and binded it to `FilterName`. What I want it to do is on every keypress, the value of `FilterName` should be updated and the filter should be triggered. Unfortunately, the filter triggers only once - when I start the application and by putting a breakpoint in the `Set` block of `FilterName`, I have discovered that it never reaches it.
Here is the declaration of the TextBox:

```
 <TextBox
         x:Name="FilterName"
         MinWidth="150"
         Margin="{StaticResource SmallTopBottomMargin}"
         Background="Transparent"
         BorderThickness="0,0,0,1"
         Text="{Binding FilterName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, IsAsync=True}"
         TextWrapping="Wrap" />
```

And here is the ViewModel:

```
        private readonly ObservableCollection<PersonData> _data;

        public ICollectionView DataCollectionView { get; }

        private string _filterName = string.Empty;

        public string FilterName
        {
            get
            {
                return _filterName;
            }
            set
            {
                _filterName = value;
                DataCollectionView.Refresh();
            }
        }

        public MainWindowViewModel(ISampleDataService sampleDataService)
        {
            //Adding the data here            

            DataCollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_data);

            DataCollectionView.Filter = FilterByName;
        }

        private bool FilterByName(object obj)
        {
            if (obj is PersonData data)
            {
                return data.Name.Contains(FilterName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
            }

            return false;
        }
```

Comment: It looks like your problem is actually just a binding issue, not related at all to filtering and datagrid, right? Are you sure you have the viewmodel you think you have?

Comment: Yes, I believe everything is correct, but the data doesn't bind. I tried setting _filterName to "fi" when declaring it (the names in _data are "first" and "second") and it filters the DataGrid correctly, but nothing happens when I try to filter it using the TextBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This binding should work provided that the view model with the `FilterName` property is the `DataContext` of the parent window:

```
Text="{Binding DataContext.FilterName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Set name of your window to `x:Name="_this"` and change the `TextBox` binding:

```xml
<TextBox   
    x:Name="tbFilterName"  
    DataContext="{Binding ElementName=_this}"                 
    Text="{Binding Path=FilterName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
    TextChanged="FilterName_TextChanged"      
    ...
```

2. Remove  `DataCollectionView.Refresh();` call from the `FilterName` setter, but add

```cs
private void FilterName_TextChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DataCollectionView.Refresh();
}
```